# How can I change between versions of python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, cmd

I am trying to use tensorflow but my python is to recent. I have python3.7.2 and I need py3.6 in order to install and use tensorflow.

I have installed py3.6.8 but I still can't install it with pip. Is there a way of interchanging between versions of python to install/use tensorflow. Or is it to do with my pip version?

The error is:
Could not find version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow in versions:

The main problem is that I don't know how to get tensorflow. Can someone help me do this?

Comment: You could use your full python path to python 3.6.8 and add -m pip install xx in command line. This will use the pip module for the specific python installation you want to use.

Comment: How is this related to [tag:cmd], the Windows Command Prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the best option will be to use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) virtual environment. After you install Anaconda, use [environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) to manage different versions of Python:

Python 3.6.8:

`conda create -n myenv python=3.6.8 tensorflow`

Python 3.7:

`conda create -n myenv python=3.7 tensorflow`

Why am I saying it's best with Anaconda? Long story short, it can be (much) faster. Here's an [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-installing-tensorflow-using-pip-for-performance-sake-5854f9d9eb0c) that discusses why.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
Install multiple versions in separate directories, and then you run the python program with the Python version you want to use. Like so:

```
C:\Python26\Python.exe thescript.py
```

What virtualenv does is that it gives you many separate "virtual" installations of the same python version. That's a completely different issue, and hence it will not help you in any way.

**Option 2:**

Use Pythonbrew.

Once pythonbrew is installed:

```
#to install new python versions is as simple as:
pythonbrew install 2.7.2 3.2
#to use a particular version in the current shell:
pythonbrew use 3.2
#to uninstall:
pythonbrew uninstall 2.7.2
```

Comment: You can have multiple Python versions with pip, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions Another option comes with Anaconda (see my answer).